# Develop on Docker container from Intellij

Tags: docker, intellij-idea

How can develop on my Docker container from Intellij? I am developing on macOS, but my development environment is inside a Docker container. In VSCode, I can use the [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension to open the files in my Docker container, go to function definitions, use the version of Go on the container, access the container shell--it's as if I am accessing a remote machine from VSCode. I didn't have to change my Dockerfile or mount any volumes. Everything just worked.

IntelliJ seems to have added something according to [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-226455), but the total functionality is unclear. I can attach to a running container using the [Docker plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker.html), access the shell, and inspect the container's attributes, but none of the above other functionality with VSCode.

Here are some examples of why this is needed:

- I am developing on macOS, but my target is specific to Intel Linux code. If I do Cmd+B on a symbol, I'm taken to a Darwin specific file
- importing github.com/docker/libnetwork fails because the files in this package can only be built for Linux

The above doesn't happen on VSCode because I can develop directly on the container.

Comment: You can access files inside the Docker container via the Files tab - https://prnt.sc/1tgxdx8

Comment: Also, I'd recommend you watch the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ck6xQqSOlpw&ab_channel=IntelliJIDEAbyJetBrains to get started with Docker in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I don't see a way to access the files as in that screenshot. It's not just about being able to access the files. I want to develop on the container from Intellij. I've updated the topic to indicate this.

Comment: A few releases ago was implemented Run Targets feature that allows running your code in another environment such as cloud or a Docker container. Please see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-targets.html#docker .

Comment: This isn't ideal for my use case. I am developing on macOS, but my target is specific to Intel Linux code. If I do Cmd+B on a symbol, I'll be taken darwin specific file. On VSCode, I'm taken to the right place. I want to be able to access the same files as the Docker container.

Comment: Hi! I'm facing the exact same issue, did you find any way to make it work?

Comment: No, I just live with this issue.